Jaxb get Root Element which validated an XML against a multiple Root Elements XSD
We have an xsd with multiple possible root elements.
The xml to validate can adopt any of them, but obviously once per xml.
I cannot divulgate the actual xsd but let's imagine something similar:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://com.sample/schema/message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://com.sample/schema/message">
    <xs:element name="FirstTypeMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
            [...]
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="SecondTypeMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
            [...]
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

In the actual xsd adopted, root elements are much more than two, and also their content can vary very much.
We cannot change the way it is done, we have to respect its standard.
We also have a Jaxb validator Java code which already works fine, this is just the "hearth" of it:
    // From parameters
    String xmlCode = "[...]" // OMISSIS the content of the xml
    String xsdFilePath = "com/sample/schema/xsd/Sample.xsd";

    [...]

    ByteArrayInputStream xmlInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlCode.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    SimpleHandler xmlParseHandler = new SimpleHandler();

    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    schemaFactory.setErrorHandler(xmlParseHandler);

    URL schemaURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(xsdFilePath);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaURL);

    Validator schemaValidator = schema.newValidator();
    schemaValidator.setErrorHandler(xmlParseHandler);

    // Validate xml instance against the grammar.
    schemaValidator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlInputStream));
    if (xmlParseHandler.getSaxParseExceptionList() != null) {
        logger.warn("WARNING : xml is not valid : " + xmlParseHandler.getSaxParseExceptionMessages().toString());
        [...]
    }

However I have necessity to define which of all Root Elements actually validated the xml.
So which sole Root Element was adopted into the current validated xml.
The project will receive a very large amount of those xml, so I'd like to adopt the lighter possible solution (i.e: no further DOM in memory).
It would be even better if Jaxb itself would tell me which Root Element validated the xml, following the validation process.

Seems that Jaxb doesn't give you such info following the validation process.
So you have to achieve the info in a separate way.
The way I chose is StAX, because lighter on resources, with something like this:
    public static String findRootElement(String xmlCode) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlCode));

        String rootElement = null;

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            if (reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                rootElement = reader.getLocalName();
                break;
            }
        }

        reader.close();
        return rootElement;
    }

This method can be implemented anywere in the code and can be used anywhere your scope knowns the xmlCode to check.
Seeing that RootElement should be one of the very first stuffs into xmlCode, this method should be very light on resources consumption.
